# What fonts to browse scala source code and render <- and =>

Tags: eclipse, scala, fonts

I'm using Eclipse on Windows 7 to browse Scala source code.  Scala allows `⇒` to be used instead of `=>`, and `←` instead of <-.

However, I can't seem to find a good clear monospace font that renders the unicode `⇒` and `←` well.  Often I just get a box instead of `⇒`.

I've tried:
  Consolas - is the clearest general font, but won't render `⇒`
  Anonymous Pro - doesn't render `⇒`
  Deja Vu Sans Mono - does render `⇒`, but it is so small it is hard to see!

For my own code, I can just avoid `⇒`, but this doesn't help viewing third party library source.  How have other folks solved this problem?  If other folks are using `⇒` in their code then presumably they also know of a monospace font that also renders it clearly :-)

Comment: [Monaco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco_(typeface)) usually renders quite readable.

Comment: Does Monaco also render the unicode  => and <- characters that are used in Scala source code?  When I just tried Monaco it didn't appear to.

Comment: I'd advise you to avoid using nifty Unicode characters and just use `=>` and `<-` instead - other people who are going to look at your code will have the same problem as you now have.

Comment: You seem to be right. In fact my version of Monaco doesn’t have these glyphs either. Apparently Eclipse on OS X is able to deal with missing glyphs and finds a fallback so I wouldn’t notice. (And curiously, the fallback looks way better than the built-in glyph in DejaVu.)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think [Inconsolata](http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-Inconsolata) works--but I use Linux, so I'm not sure it will work for you on Windows.</strike>

Inconsolata doesn't have the glyph.  Your best bet is to take Deja Vu Sans Mono and edit the right-double-arrow glyph to be bigger.  I just did it using FontForge on Linux; it took me about 5 minutes.

Here's an example before and after (after is on the bottom):

[image: Default and edited Deja Vu Sans Mono double right arrow]

Comment: Thanks.  But alas it doesn't appear to work.  I seem to just get an empty space rather than the desired symbol.  The Inconsolata font also seems to render very faintly on Windows.

Comment: @RobWilton - Pity.  It's quite nice on Linux (both weight and existence of symbol).

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately don't know if they also support Unicode characters and if one of them is to your liking, but give [Source Code Pro](http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2012/09/source-code-pro.html) and [Droid Sans Mono](https://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Droid+Sans+Mono) a try. I guess you googled already, but this [arbitrary list](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30040/Font-Survey-42-of-the-Best-Monospaced-Programming) of 42 monospaced fonts might drop some new names nevertheless.

I am personally quite happy with DejaVu Sans Mono, but I agree that the arrow (amongst other characters) is not the nicest.

On a related note: I am always impressed by how well browsers (Firefox in my case) display all kinds of wired Unicode characters. If I remember correctly, then they apply a kind of fallback strategy. That is, if the main font cannot handle a character, a (or multiple) fallback fonts are tried. I don't assume that you can use such a method directly, but searching along those lines might yield other potential solutions to your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I've just downloaded and tried both Source Code Pro and Droid Sans Mono, but neither of them render the right arrow.  Word also plays in a similar way to the web browsers, substituting for a different font if the glyph isn't present.